# IntelliJ unit tests don't see changes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem with my Java(Spring-Boot) unit tests on IntelliJ. My actual code and the test-code are on the same module. When I make a change in my code and I want to test it, I right click on the test class and "Run Test" But it doesn't see the actual code change I made earlier, unless I do a "mvn clean install" before I run the test each time(?!)

I might be wrong but I think this problem started after I converted my project into a multi module project. Though as I said in this case all code is in the same module. So cant see the relavance, Any suggestions how can I overcome with weird inconvenient behaviour?

Comment: Intellij has a separate build process that it uses. There is a menu at the top called build, and you can re-trigger a build with CTRL+F9

Comment: Show me your build configuration - maybe you dont have build step in it(thus no build prior run, thus no changes)

Comment: It's been a while since I used IntelliJ, but i THINK I remember that there was something you could do in the build configuration that will auto-build after each change? Sorry for the vagueness, but I think Antoniossss is on to something

Comment: Thanks for tips. I just realized that I cant even make a "Build". Probably thats the real issue. I get all sorts of package and symbol not found errors. Since I only use maven didnt notice there was a problem in build. I did an invalidate caches restart on Intellij but still same problem!

Comment: @DanielSchmidt Problem solved. I deleted the ".idea" folder and restarted. Then Builds started to work fine, hence the tests. Thanks for leading in right direction, if someone answers this I will accept it.

Comment: You can also edit the run configuration and make it run `mvn clean test-compile` automatically each time you hit run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comments I realized that I cant even make a "Build", that was the real issue. I got all sorts of package and symbol not found errors. I tried to "Invalidate caches restart" on Intellij but didnt help. So I deleted the **".idea"** folder and restarted IntelliJ. Then the errors in "build" disappeared, hence the tests was able to make a build after a change. Thanks for leading in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the issue of IntelliJ caching some classes in combination with unit test execution quite often. Especially after deleting or moving classes, IntelliJ does not seem to realize that classes are now gone or located within a different package.

So far, I was able to solve the issue via triggering a rebuild of the project:

*Go to:* `Build` > `Rebuild Project`